# issue with myphpadmin resulting in blank table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm experimenting with sql/ php etc.. So I been creating a airbnb mockup to learn from. I got to a point where the button for my form populates the server. However, it doesn't actually populate it with data.

Can someone look this over and see where I went wrong?

html
[image: html]
php

```
<?php
    include_once('db.php');

    $search_id = (isset($_POST['search_id']) ? $_POST['search_id'] : null); //primary key for A.I.

    $location = (isset($_POST['location']) ? $_POST['location'] : null);
    $check_in = (isset($_POST['check_in']) ? $_POST['check_in'] : null);
    $check_out = (isset($_POST['check_out']) ? $_POST['check_out'] : null);
    $number_adults = (isset($_POST['number_adults']) ? $_POST['number_adults'] : null);
    $number_children = (isset($_POST['number_children']) ? $_POST['number_children'] : null);

    $result = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO airbnb (location, check_in, check_out, number_adults, number_children) VALUES('$location', '$check_in', '$check_out', '$number_adults', '$number_children')");



    if($result){
      echo "Successfully Inserted";
    }
    else{
      echo "Insertion Failed";
    }
?>
```

For results--> if I click submit button on the form below.

[image: form]
I get the result of Successfully Inserted from the index php.

However, on the database I only get data from the incremented primary key;

[image: php]

Can someone see where I'm missing something?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Dharman its ok for now haha its just test

Comment: Did you do some basic debugging? What does `var_dump($_POST);` show?

Comment: No, it is never ok, it could even be the cause of your problem and a solution to this question. Besides you are spreading bad programming practices on the internet.

Comment: @lovelace Insertedarray(0) { } ah i see lol

Comment: yep, it's often that easy... look at @Dharman's answer

Comment: Also your labels do not match your input ID attributes.

Comment: @Dharman yea I just noticed that and fixed it :p

Answer (score 1):

Your input fields in HTML do not have `name` attributes. If the fields are not named they will not be send to the server.

```
<input type="text" name="location" id="location" />
```

Will be send to PHP as `$_POST['location'];`